# Unity does not get listed in lightdm on xubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity

I've installed Xubuntu 13.04 beta2 and installed unity but it's not getting listed in lightdm session list. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The list of sessions is defined by the .desktop files in `/usr/share/xsessions`. There should be ubuntu.desktop containing entry for Unity.

On my Ubuntu (12.10 with GDM) the ubuntu.desktop file contains the following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

But there is a possibility that your should look different.